# Lightbox problem loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, lightbox

I just uploaded Lightbox in my website using the code from this http://www.flashxml.net/3d-carousel-menu.html

If I click the images in Firefox, images open fine. But if I try it with IE 8, the images don't enlarge or Lightbox doesn't work.

Here is the site:

http://www.wikima4.com/index.php?id=423

Error I got in IE:

```
 Webpage error details

 User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;   .NET4.0C; AskTbFXTV5/5.9.1.14019)
 Timestamp: Tue, 30 Nov 2010 13:57:36 UTC


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 42
    Char: 3
    Code: 0
    URI: http://www.wikima4.com/assets/snippets/ajaxSearch/js/ajaxSearch.js


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 153
    Char: 107
    Code: 0
    URI: http://www.wikima4.com/manager/media/script/mootools/mootools.js


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 567
    Char: 3
    Code: 0
    URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 567
    Char: 3
    Code: 0
    URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


   Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
   Line: 567
   Char: 3
   Code: 0
   URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
  Line: 567
  Char: 3
  Code: 0
  URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
  Line: 567
   Char: 3
  Code: 0
  URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


 Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
 Line: 567
 Char: 3
 Code: 0
 URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
  Line: 567
  Char: 3
  Code: 0
   URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
  Line: 567
  Char: 3
  Code: 0
  URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


   Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
   Line: 567
   Char: 3
   Code: 0
   URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js


  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
  Line: 567
  Char: 3
  Code: 0
  URI: http://www.wikima4.com/js/effects.js
```

Comment: IE is throwing a JavaScript error - see if you can find it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this? as I don't have any idea about debugging. Thanks

Comment: IE will show an error symbol bottom left or bottom right. It's not very good at directing you to the actual source of the error unfortunately, but it may give you a clue. Sorry, can't help much more than that!

Comment: ok. thanks I saw it. I'm getting this error. Please see my above edited questions.

Comment: There are many javascripts missing in your page. I is possible that IE just chokes on one of the missing scripts and because of it can't run your lightbox correctly. If I were you I should start by fixing them first.   webkit-focusfix.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
dragdrop.j sFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
builder.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

etc.

Comment: This question relies on an external link, and as such we cannot know if the site has the same problem as it did ten years ago (one would hope that was now fixed). As such this question is missing a [mcve] and it should ideally be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a developer console that you can use for much more detailed debugging.

- Tools
- Developer Tools

**or**

- **F12**

I ran through on the page and it looks like it's throwing 2 errors on load, the first is in `prototype.js`

> 'Object doesn't support this property
>   or method' - prototype.js, line 448
>   character 5

```
var Enumerable = {
  each: function(iterator) {
    var index = 0;
    try {
      this._each(function(value) {
        iterator(value, index++);
      });
  breaks here-->} catch (e) {
      if (e != $break) throw e;
    }
    return this;
  },
```

The second is in `mootools.js`, line 153 character 107

> 'Object doesn't support this property
>   or method' = mootools.js, line 153
>   character 107

```
this.fireEvent("domready");
```

I can't reproduce the issue, but I'd suggest Googling about possible conflicts others have experienced using the different scripts together. See if possibly that's the issue, also if the frameworks you are using have updated you may try using the newer frameworks to see if any updates corrected your issue.

The MSDN Overviews and Tutorials on the Developer Tools in IE8: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Good Luck

Comment: I will check on this one and will let you know. Thanks for the link